# Are Spring Converters for the web layer (problem with @WebMvcTest)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-test

I'm writing a test which is annotated with `@WebMvcTest`. Apart from the specified controller, this also loads all custom `Converter`s.

The problem is that the application for which I'm writing the test uses these converters in the service layer, and, even worse, that these converters (unfortunately) have dependencies to the database layer and to many other beans. Therefore, starting the WebMvcTest fails due to unfulfilled dependencies of the converters. My workaround is to put all converters into the `@MockBean` annotation.

This makes me wonder what these converters are exactly made for. If they are designed for the web layer to implicitely convert controller arguments, it would be fine to load them in a WebMvcTest, but then they should not have any other dependencies.

But if they don't have any arguments, what would be the advantage of them to use over simple Java method calls? Why would one need beans for them?

Comment: `Converter` s are general components for converting from type x to type y. They can be used anywhere.